# Print a list and another variable without the brackets and commas

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables

I want to print a predefined list and a variable behind it. My code is below:

```
sent = 0
to_addr = ['email@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
sent = sent + 1
print('Email sent to: %s '(', '.join(to_addr)))
```

What is want the output to look like is this:

Email sent to: email@email.com, email2@email.com (1)

Comment: change the last line to `print('Email sent to: %s ' % (', '.join(to_addr)))`

Comment: or use `f-string` like `print(f'Email sent to: {", ".join(to_addr)}')`

Comment: how would you add the ```sent``` variable in?

Comment: to indicate how many people the mail was sent to ? what does the sent variable represent?

Comment: `print(f'Email sent to: {", ".join(to_addr)} ({sent})')`

Comment: `print('Email sent to: '+(', '.join(to_addr))+' ('+str(sent)+')')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an f-string and an intermediate string to store Emails string as follows:

```
sent = 0
to_addr = ['email@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
sent = sent + 1
adress_list = ', '.join(to_addr)
print(f'Email sent to: {adress_list}, ({sent})')
```

with the code above I obtain the result below:
Email sent to: email@email.com, email2@email.com, (1)